# Handling iOS keyboard focus events in javascript

Tags: javascript

The user can switch the focus to the (previous / next) element (input field, textarea, select) inside a form with these keys (image bellow) but how do i handle the events? They are not keys as such so using `keypress` or `keyup` naturally doesn't work.

The problem is i need to execute some code when the user clicks on one of these arrows, and **not** when the browser switches focus to another element.

[image: iOS keyboard arrows]